# Ubuntu 12.04lts overheating laptop

Tags: 12.04, overheating

I have been using elementary OS, for quiet along time.
Its based of Ubuntu, and once I got sick of no customization options,
I went for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
Now this overheats my laptop constantly, it takes some time but it get so hot
I can smell it and then (luckly) shuts down.

Why is this happening? when Eos was so stable?

(laptop: acer aspire 7741g, intel i5, radeon hd5650)

Comment: Close voters: Please explain how this is off-topic or not constructive. Please remember that this user is *not* using ElementaryOS, and *is* using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem on my Avell notebook uninstaling the actual kernel and instaling a 3.2.x-xx kernel. There are other kernel versions that also do not have this bug.

You can do it using a tool like [Synaptic [image: Install synaptic]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic).

1. Check the actual version of your kernel with the command

   ```
   uname -r
   ```

   in a terminal.
2. Then mark the kernel files for complete removal in Synaptic, and mark the desired kernel to install.
3. After removing the trouble kernel and installing the good kernel, open a terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot.

This worked for me.

This problem is because some kernel releases does not handle the thermal control of the CPU appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because of kernel (linux)
the best way to get red of overheating or at least reduce it is upgrading your ubuntu to 12.10 or compile a higher version of linux (kernel) like 3.4

Comment: This is over simplifying, there is no guarantee that 12.10 will be better, neither for a "higher" kernel.

Comment: I said the best way not the way. yeah you are right there is no guaranty.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that the 3D desktop goodness is giving that AMD video a run for its money (Or there are bad/no 3D drivers). If it's reasonable, I'd try either a simpler window manager, or try to install first party video drivers.